How can I get item [n] from every array in a dictionary?
I've got a data structure Dictionary<int, float[]> and I want to generate a float[] which is the nth entry from each float[].  I can do this in code:
float[] rowData = new float[rawData.Count];
for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
{
    int col = 0;
    foreach (var key in keys)
        rowData[col++] = rawData[key][row];

Is there a clever way to do this using Linq so I don't need the "foreach"?

so count of keys in the dictionary is the same as the length of each array?

Iterating over most Dictionary types in .NET has undefined ordering which means your rowData array won't contain values in any particular order - but typically an array is used to represent data with a well-defined order - otherwise you could use a more abstract type.

...so based on that, this looks like an X/Y Problem. Please tell us what your underlying question/problem is (i.e. why are you doing this in the first place?)

I think what you're looking for is a simple select:
var nthRow = 1; // or whatever n is
var rowData = rawData.Select(kvp => kvp.Value[nthRow]).ToArray();

Please note that nthRow must be inside the bounds of the smallest array in the dictionary, otherwise you'll get an IndexOutOfRangeException.
The following code will produce a float[] with the values [0.2, 1.2, 2.2]*:
Dictionary<int, float[]> rawData = new () {
    {1, [0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f]},
    {2, [1.0f, 1.1f, 1.2f, 1.3f]},
    {3, [2.0f, 2.1f, 2.2f, 2.3f]},
};

var nthRow = 2;
var rowData = rawData.Select(kvp => kvp.Value[nthRow]).ToArray();

*Please note, however, that a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is an unordered collection, where the only guarantee for order is that an iteration of its Keys will always be in the same order as an iteration of its Values - so the order of the values inside the final float[] array is not guaranteed.

Let's state the problem:

Given n >= 0 and rawData dictionary, we want to obtain nth item from Values when it exists

If it's your task then Linq can be
var rowData = rawData
  .Values                           // Values, i.e. arrays   
  .Where(array => array.Length > n) // Which have at least n items
  .Select(array => array[n])        // Take n-th item
  .ToArray();                       // Materialize as array

If you want to provide some defaultItem if array is too short:
var rowData = rawData
  .Values                           
  .Select(array => array.Length >= n ? array[n] : defaultItem)
  .ToArray();                       

